# React component test with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, components, enzyme

I have a component like this:

component.js

```
 import React from "react";
 import PropTypes from "prop-types";

 const Test = ({ text }) => (
 <div>
  {text.split("\n").map((item, key) => {
  return (
    <span key={key}>
      {item}
      <br />
    </span>
    );
    })}
  </div>
 );

 Test.propTypes = {
 text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
 };

 export default Test;
```

How do i write component test for this react component using enzyme? I am new to react and enzyme. Any help will really appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a test using mocha:

```
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'
import assert from 'assert'
import Test from './Test'

describe('component Test', () => {
  it('should show a span for each line of "text" prop', () => {
    const text = `foo
    bar
    `
    const wrapper = shallow(<Test text={text} />)
    const spans = wrapper.find('span')
    assert.equal(spans.length, 2)
    assert.equal(spans.at(0).text(), 'foo')
    assert.equal(spans.at(1).text(). 'bar')
  })

  it('should throw if "text" prop is not provided', () => {
    assert.throws(() => {
      shallow(<Text />)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is shamelessly taken [example](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html#dom-testing) of testing dom using enzyme + jest (from jest [web site](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html#content)):

```
// __tests__/CheckboxWithLabel-test.js

import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import CheckboxWithLabel from '../CheckboxWithLabel';

test('CheckboxWithLabel changes the text after click', () => {
  // Render a checkbox with label in the document
  const checkbox = shallow(
    <CheckboxWithLabel labelOn="On" labelOff="Off" />
  );

  expect(checkbox.text()).toEqual('Off');

  checkbox.find('input').simulate('change');

  expect(checkbox.text()).toEqual('On');
});
```

I recommend you to go though the link I gave - it contains nice examples of testing react components using Jest + Enzyme.